# Do not allow '&*' pair Textarea in Java Script

Tags: javascript, textarea

While adding text in a textarea, I dont want to allow '*' after '&'.

I want to check on Asterisk keypress, whether previous symbol added is '&', if yes, user cannot add '*'.

Kindly help, how to  proceed.

Comment: Although this can certainly be tested I'm curious as to why you are trying? Is this a client side attempt to avoid SQL Injection or similar? If so, JavaScript is not the answer.  If this is something else, you don't just want to do it on keypress of asterisks, as a backspace press on `&_*` might also result in the same issue.  I'd suggest a regex on the entire content on any keypress.

Comment: PS are you using any JavaScript Libraries? jQuery, MooTools, Prototype? etc.

Comment: '&*' forms a delimiter for a string passed to action class in struts. So, dont want this pair!

Comment: Hm, if Struts is really doing that (I had honestly a wtf? moment), then I would really favor server side validation over client side validation for this. JavaScript can be disabled/spoofed, requests can be tampered, URLs can be edited, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be better off having a general function that runs after *every* "keyup" event which cleans up the textarea by removing any asterisks (`*`) immediately after an ampersand (`&`).  This way, even if the user pastes some content which contains the invalid sequence (`&*`) it will still be cleaned up.  So something like this:

```
myTextArea.onkeyup = function() {
  myTextArea.value = myTextArea.value.replace(/&\*/, '&');
  return true;
};
```

Comment: I'd add a check if the value contains `&*` otherwise this may go mad when the user types faster than the function runs.

Comment: Great! If you think that this answer solves your problem then consider pressing the checkmark to indicate that this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 55 && input.value.substr(input.value.length - 1) === "*") {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },false);
```

This will add an event to check the incoming character and the last in the current input. If the incoming is shift+55 (thats shift-7 or &) and the last character in the input is "*" preventDefault will bail out of the event and not input what was just typed. This example wont work in IE because its using addEventListener but the same approach will work with IE attachEvent or event jQuery events for full cross browser.

Comment: But if the user pastes the text `&*` it will still be present!

Answer (score 0):

Because you can paste using contextual menu, Ctrl-V, Shift-Ins, etc...

```
myTextArea.onchange = function() {
  myTextArea.value = myTextArea.value.replace(/&\*/, '&');
  return true;
};
```

And of course, this does not replace a good server side validation